# Reacr Router - setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an app that's using React Router. The app has some components which constantly update (it's a dashboard for live analytics data). I'm running into the following error when using `<Link>` to link around various sections of the dashboard:

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or
>   mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   Logins component.

Here is my code:

**App.js:**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Main />    
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Main.js:**

```
<Sidenav />
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/site-feedback' component={Sitefeedback}/>
    <Route exact path='/logins' component={Logins}/>
    <Route exact path='/shop-sales' component={Shopsales}/>
</Switch>
```

**Sidenav.js:**

```
<Link to='/site-feedback'>Site Feedback</Link>
<Link to="/logins">Logins</Link>
<Link to="/shop-sales">Shop Sales</Link>
```

If I replace the `<links>` with just normal a-tags then the issue goes away as the entire app loads again but I would ideally like to not have to reload other components I have in there like header or sidenav for example.

Anyone know a good workaround for this? I can't imagine i'm the only person that's experienced this issue with React Router...

Thanks

Comment: The warning is self-explaining: _..Please check the code for the **Logins** component._

Comment: What do you have running in Login component?

Comment: Did you mean to write `<Route exact path='/logins' component={Logins}/>` and `<Route exact path='/shop-sales' component={Shopsales}/>`?

Comment: A lot of things @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi

Comment: Yes I did @KhauriMcClain, have updated the code now

Comment: Do you have a setInterval? and inside that do you have a function that call setState?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are good that one of your components sets up an interval or subscribes to an external event. You need to unsubscribe from all the events and clear all the timeouts/intervals in the `componentWillUnmount`, it should look like this:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timeoutId = setInterval(...)
    subscribeToSomeEvent(...)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timeoutId)
    unsubscribeFromSomeEvent(...)
  }
}
```

Another reason why you may get that message is when a user changes a page (and thus unmounts the current component) while some ajax request is in progress, and once the request completes it tries to update the unmounted component. You can set up some flag to avoid those late updates:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(...).then(data => {
      if (this.unmounted) return
      // process the data
    })
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unmounted = true
  }
}
```

Comment: The second reason fixed the issue for me. Thank you!